# What are the differences between os.putenv(key, value) and os.environ[key]=value in python?

Tags: python, operating-system

I need build a system environ variable, and I use `os.putenv(key, value)` to build one, then `print os.getenv(key)`, the console outputs `None`.

But the console outputs value (here is `print os.getenv(key)` or `print os.environ[key]`) when I use `os.environ[key] = value` to build it.

However, the key and the value are not in the dictionary if `print os.environ`.

Why can I not build the system environment variable successfully? I use Windows 7 and Python 2.7.5.

Comment: It's a good practice to restore the environment variables at function completion.
You may need something like the `modified_environ` context manager describe in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34333710/1513933) to restore the environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters) you will get the answer to why os.putenv does not work:

> This mapping is captured the first time the os module is imported, typically during
>   Python startup as part of processing site.py. Changes to the environment made after
>   this time are not reflected in os.environ, except for changes made by modifying
>   os.environ directly.
>
> If the platform supports the putenv() function, this mapping may be used to modify the
>   environment as well as query the environment. putenv() will be called automatically
>   when the mapping is modified.
>
> Note Calling putenv() directly does not change os.environ, so it’s better to modify
>   os.environ.

Comment: okay, I use os.environ[key]=value to build a system environ variable successfully in python shell. But why does not the system environ variable exist if I shutdown the python shell?

Comment: I knew that the system environ variable only exists in current python shell, I must import _winreg module to build the system environ variable if I want the system environ variable to save in windows operating-system. BTW, thanks a lot for your patient interpretation. :D