# python os.environ, os.putenv, /usr/bin/env

Tags: python

I want to ensure `os.system('env')` not contain some specific variable `myname`
which is export in `~/.bashrc` as `export myname=csj`

Therefore, I wrote below python code:

```
import os

def print_all():
    print "os.environ['myname']=%s" % os.environ.get('myname')
    print "os.getenv('myname')=%s" % os.getenv('myname')
    os.system('env | grep myname')
    print

def delete_myname():
    if 'myname' in os.environ: os.environ.pop('myname')
    if os.getenv('myname'): os.unsetenv('myname')

print_all()

os.putenv('myname', 'csj2')
print "---------------------"
delete_myname()
print_all()

os.putenv('myname', 'csj3')
print "---------------------"
delete_myname()
print_all()
```

I think examine both `os.environ['myname']` and `os.getenv('myname')` 
and then delete them if exist, 
can ensure `os.system('env | grep myname')` get nothing.

However, the result is:

```
os.environ['myname']=csj
os.getenv('myname')=csj
myname=csj

---------------------
os.environ['myname']=None
os.getenv('myname')=None

---------------------
os.environ['myname']=None
os.getenv('myname')=None
myname=csj3
```

I don't understand why I still got `csj3` on `os.system('env | grep myname')`?

Comment: It looks like there is some sort of race condition occurring. Do you get the same results consistently? If you add a 4th round, does `myname=csj3` persist, or only `myname=csj4` in the 4th round?

Comment: it got the same result always. Actually in my real python script, there are many stuff/code between the second putenv(), very confuse me ..Now I put a time.sleep(1) before 2nd putenv(), and `while [ 1 ]; do python env.py ; sleep 1; done` to execute the script, got the same result always.

Comment: if I delete one line `if 'myname' in os.environ: os.environ.pop('myname')`, amazingly, I got nothing on `os.system('env | grep myname')` and seems solve the problem. Although I still don't know why...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.environ):

> **Note:** Calling putenv() directly does not change os.environ, so it’s better to modify os.environ.

For `unsetenv` there is a similar warining:

> however, calls to unsetenv() don’t update os.environ, so it is actually preferable to delete items of os.environ.

`getenv` just returns the value from `os.environ`, as it's [implementation shows](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7b81a535ad14/Lib/os.py#l740), so by using it you get into a state where it seems the value isn't set when you look it up from python, while it acutally is in the real environment. The only way to get it now I can think of would be to call the c getenv function using ctypes...

If i modify your code to use `os.environ` isnstead of calling `putenv`/`unsetenv` everything works as expected:

```
import os

def print_all():
    print "os.environ['myname']=%s" % (os.environ['myname'] if 'myname' in os.environ else "None")
    os.system('env | grep myname')
    print

def delete_myname():
    if 'myname' in os.environ: os.environ.pop('myname')

print_all()

os.environ['myname'] = 'csj2'
print "---------------------"
print_all()
delete_myname()
print_all()

os.environ['myname'] = 'csj3'
print "---------------------"
print_all()
delete_myname()
print_all()
```

output:

```
$ myname=somevalue python2 test.py 
os.environ['myname']=somevalue
myname=somevalue

---------------------
os.environ['myname']=csj2
myname=csj2

os.environ['myname']=None

---------------------
os.environ['myname']=csj3
myname=csj3

os.environ['myname']=None
```

Comment: Yes, I think if only use os.environ can ensure /usr/bin/env not have the variable... but cause other team's script use putenv() to do something, and I call their script. I don't have very good reason to convince them to change their code. I just want try to delete it myself.

Comment: Show them the the note in the documentation for putenv/unsetenv, and that getenv just returns whatever is in `os.environ`. That should convince them.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice could be:

- delete the `myname` environment variable (if it exists),
- run your function
- restore the `myname` environment variable at function completion.

Yu can do that easily with something like the `modified_environ` context manager describe in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333710/1513933).

```
with modified_environ('myname'):
    call_my_function()
```