# Environment variables missing in Spyder

Tags: python

I'm running Spyder 2.5.3.2 with Python 2.7 on mac.

Spyder is complaining when I try to load a specific dynamic library, and the issue seems to be that `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is missing from my environment variables. I can see the rest of the definitions from my `.bash_profile` file here, but `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is missing.

When I run the same python binary in the terminal and call `os.environ` I can see `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` and the dynamic library loading works fine.

Is Spyder stripping this environment variable out for some reason, and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: you can set environment variables with `os.environ`, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705419/python-os-environ-os-putenv-usr-bin-env