# Pyspark don't recognize env variables on the method passed as argument to foreach or foreachPartition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, redis-py

In my  code below I try to instantiate [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)
connection using env variable at URL. The problem is that when I use [foreach or foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) the env variable isn't recognized in #save_on_redis method.

I just try to create redis connection outside, but I receive *"pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'lock' object"*, because spark try to run these two methods, at the same time, on all nodes.

> Question: How I can use env variables on the method passed as argument to foreach or foreachPartition ?

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import redis

spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .getOrCreate())

print "---------"
print os.getenv("REDIS_REPORTS_URL")
print "---------"

def save_on_redis(row):
    redis_ = redis.StrictRedis(host=os.getenv("REDIS_REPORTS_URL"), port=6379, db=0)
    print os.getenv("REDIS_REPORTS_URL")
    print redis_
    redis_.set("#teste#", "fagner")


df  = spark.createDataFrame([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2)], ["id", "score"])
df.foreach(save_on_redis)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to get env variable in your driver process and pass it as a python variable to worker processes, where you could set your environment with using `os.putenv`

Example:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: a = sc.parallelize(range(20))

In [3]: os.getenv('MY_VAR')
Out[3]: 'some_value'

In [4]: def f(iter):
    import os
    return (str(os.getenv('MY_VAR')),)
   ...:

In [5]: a.mapPartitions(f).collect()
Out[5]: ['None', 'None']

In [6]: my_var = os.getenv('MY_VAR')

In [6]: def f2(iter):
    import os
    from subprocess import check_output
    os.putenv('MY_VAR', my_var)
    return (check_output('env | grep MY_VAR', shell=True), my_var)
   ....:

In [7]: a.mapPartitions(f2).collect()
Out[7]:
['MY_VAR=some_value\n',
 'some_value',
 'MY_VAR=some_value\n',
 'some_value']
```

PS. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705935/5167302), it is preferable to directly modify `os.environ` mapping object rather than use `os.putenv`