# How to set and retrieve environment variable in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I need to set a environment variables in the python, and I try the commands bellow

```
import os
basepath = os.putenv('CPATH','/Users/cat/doc') 
basepath = os.getenv('CPATH','/Users/cat/doc')
```

And when I print the varible, they are not set:
    print basepath
    None

What i'm doing wrong?

Rephrasing the question, I would like to create a base path based on a evironment variable. I'm testing this:

```
os.environ["CPATH"] = "/Users/cat/doc"
print os.environ["CPATH"]
base_path=os.getenv('C_PATH')
```

And when I try to print the basepath:
    print basepath
it always return
None

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: OS X Mavericks (version 10.9)

Comment: Are you using Flask ?

Comment: @Ofiris: I'm having this problem and I am using Flask. `os.getenv('PATH') == os.environ('PATH') == os.environ.get('PATH') == None`. Got advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one.

```
os.environ["CPATH"] = "/Users/cat/doc"
```

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters) is quite clear about it.

> Calling putenv() directly does not change os.environ, so it’s better to modify os.environ.

Based on the documentation, the `os.getenv()` is available on most flavors of Unix and Windows. OS X is not listed.

Use rather the snippet below to retrieve the value.

```
value = os.environ.get('CPATH')
```

Comment: In this way I can print the env variable but when I try to ascribe it to a base path, eg:                                           base_path = os.getenv('CPATH')

Comment: @CatarinaCM, pardon? Modifying `os.environ` quite certainly does update the environment variables active for your script -- and `base_path = os.environ.get('CPATH')` [if you want `None` in the not-found case] is the best-practices approach to retrieval. If you're seeing contrary results, please provide a reproducer so we know how you're testing.

Comment: Use `os.environ.get('CPATH')` as @Charles suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
os.environ['CPATH'] = '/Users/cat/doc'    
print os.environ['CPATH']     # /Users/cat/doc
print os.environ.get('CPATH') # /Users/cat/doc
```

See the above [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) for more details:

> If the platform supports the putenv() function, this mapping may be
>   used to modify the environment as well as query the environment.
>   putenv() will be called automatically when the mapping is modified.
>
> Note Calling putenv() directly does not change os.environ, so **it’s
>   better to modify os.environ.**

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to restore the environment variables at function completion.
You may need something like the `modified_environ` context manager describe in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333710/1513933) to restore the environment variables.

Usage example:

```
with modified_environ(CPATH='/Users/cat/doc'):
    call_my_function()
```