# Python mock Patch os.environ and return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, dependency-injection, mocking

Unit testing conn() using mock:

app.py

```py
import mysql.connector
import os, urlparse


def conn():
    if "DATABASE_URL" in os.environ:
        url = urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=url.username,
            password=url.password,
            host=url.hostname,
            database=url.path[1:],
        )
    else:
        return "Error"
```

test.py

```py
def test_conn(self):
    with patch(app.mysql.connector) as mock_mysql:
        with patch(app.os.environ) as mock_environ:
            con()
            mock_mysql.connect.assert_callled_with("credentials")
```

Error: *Assertion* `mock_mysql.connect.assert_called_with` is not called.

which I believe it is because 'Database_url' is not in my patched `os.environ` and because of that test call is not made to mysql_mock.connect.

Questions:

1. What changes do I need to make this test code work?
2. Do I also have to patch `urlparse`?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can try [unittest.mock.patch.dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) solution. Just call `conn` with a `dummy` argument:

```
import mysql.connector
import os, urlparse
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"DATABASE_URL": "mytemp"}, clear=True)  # why need clear=True explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477901/248616
# If clear is true then the dictionary will be cleared before the new values are set.
def conn(mock_A):
    print os.environ["mytemp"]
    if "DATABASE_URL" in os.environ:
        url = urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=url.username,
            password=url.password,
            host=url.hostname,
            database=url.path[1:],
        )
    else:
        return "Error"
```

Or if you don't want to modify your original function try this solution:

```
import os
from unittest import mock

def func():
    print os.environ["mytemp"]


def test_func():
    k = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"mytemp": "mytemp"})
    k.start()
    func()
    k.stop()


test_func()
```

Comment: As it doesn't make a difference for the question / answer, I removed the wrong Python code from both :-)

Comment: I just want to highlight the `patch.dict()` option `clear=True`! I intuitively expected this to be the default behavior, plus the `unittest` docs examples are technically correct but give the wrong impression, and don't highlight the `clear` option.

Answer (score 52):

For this, I find that [pytest's monkeypatch fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) leads to better code when you need to set environment variables:

```
def test_conn(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('DATABASE_URL', '<URL WITH CREDENTIAL PARAMETERS>')
    with patch(app.mysql.connector) as mock_mysql:
        conn()
    mock_mysql.connect.assert_called_with(<CREDENTIAL PARAMETERS>)
```

Comment: this gives me `AttributeError: 'MockFixture' object has no attribute 'setenv'`

Comment: This works for me, using `pytest==3.5.0`. @SonicSoul maybe your version is different?

Comment: @SonicSoul make sure to include `monkeypatch` in the test arguments

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is correct.  Here's a decorator `@mockenv` to do the same.  Note this doesn't depend on `monkeypatch` so it works outside of pytest presumably

```py
def mockenv(**envvars):
    return mock.patch.dict(os.environ, envvars)


@mockenv(DATABASE_URL="foo", EMAIL="bar@gmail.com")
def test_something():
    assert os.getenv("DATABASE_URL") == "foo"
```

Answer (score 15):

In my use case, I was trying to mock having NO environmental variable set. To do that, make sure you add `clear=True` to your patch.

```
with patch.dict(os.environ, {}, clear=True):
    func()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

At the head of your file mock environ before importing your module:

```
with patch.dict(os.environ, {'key': 'mock-value'}):
    import your.module
```

Comment: This helped me out because the key and value I needed were required at import time rather than at the time of the function call

Answer (score 3):

You can also use something like the `modified_environ` context manager describe in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333710/1513933) to set/restore the environment variables.

```
with modified_environ(DATABASE_URL='mytemp'):
    func()
```

Answer (score 2):

Little improvement to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579887)

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"DATABASE_URL": "foo", "EMAIL": "bar@gmail.com"})
def test_something():
    assert os.getenv("DATABASE_URL") == "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved for me, I had to give the same before my import of class.

```
mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"CONFIG_SERVER_PATH": "config_path", "CONFIG_SERVER_PROFILE": "config_profile"}).start()
from Class.module import function
```