# Environment variables with pytest and tox

Tags: python, pytest, tox

How can I test environment variables using pytest and tox?

## validate.py

```
ENV_VAR = os.environ['ENV_VAR']

def validate_env_var(value):
    if value != ENV_VAR:
        raise Exception
```

## test_validate.py

```
class TestValidateEnvVar:
    def test_validate_env_var_pass(self):
        value = 'valid_env_value'
        os.environ["ENV_VAR"] = value
        validate.validate_env_var(value)
```

If I set the environment variables in the `tox.ini` file:

```
[testenv]
setenv = ENV_VAR=valid_env_value
```

The test passes, but I would like to keep the test isolated.

Comment: you mean you'd like to cleanup the env. variables after the test right?

Comment: for this case, I'm trying to get the test to pass without setting the environment variable using the tox.ini file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variables should be provided by your test, not by your test runner. One option is to use [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and [patch `os.environ`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582750/python-mock-patch-os-environ-and-return-value/31583528). Alternatively you can just provide the environment variables in your test case's `setUp()` and reset them in `tearDown()`.

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with the `ENV_VAR` variable getting set before the test would run.
The `validate` module had to be reloaded within the test to work properly using `imp.reload`

## test_validate.py

```
import mock
from imp import reload
class TestValidateEnvVar:
    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"ENV_VAR": "env_value"})
    def test_validate_env_var_pass(self):
        reload(validate)
        value = 'env_value'
        os.environ["ENV_VAR"] = value
        validate.validate_env_var(value)
```