# Mocking Only One Function of a Class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, psycopg2

I would like to write a unit test that can ensure a SQL statement in a function call is schematically correct. It should test the execution of this call. I would then like to mock the call to commit, so that no insertions to the database take place. I'm using psycopg2 for my tests.

I have a function like:

```
def test_insert(a, b, c):
    con = psycopg2.connect(os.environ['PGDB'])
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('insert into test_table values ({a}, {b}, {c})'.format(a=a, b=b, c=c))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

when calling `test_insert(1,2,3)` I see the row inserted into the table. Now I try to mock the call. I've taken a few approaches so far:

```
@mock.patch('psycopg2.connect')
def test(mock_connect, a, b, c):
    mock_con = mock_connect.return_value
    mock_con.commit.return_value = None
    insert_row(a, b, c)
```

This seems to work but does not actually call the execution statement. `test_insert(1,4,'xyz')` fails for instance while `test(1,4,'xyz')` does not. Next I tried to mock just the commit method of the connection class in psycopg2:

```
@mock.patch('psycopg2.extensions.connection.commit')
def test_insert(mock_commit, a, b, c):
    mock_commit.return_value = None
    insert_row(a,b,c)
```

but this gives me a syntax error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/a/.virtualenv/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1318, in patched
    patching.__exit__(*exc_info)
  File "/home/a/.virtualenv/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1480, in __exit__
    setattr(self.target, self.attribute, self.temp_original)
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'psycopg2.extensions.connection'
```

Is there a good way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/) and it is not a good practice to name your functions starting with `test_` if they are not actual tests as this will probably raise problems with the testing framework. Therefore I slightly modified your initial snippet as follows and I named the module `psyco.py`

```
import psycopg2
import os

def insert(a, b, c):
    con = psycopg2.connect(os.environ['PGDB'])
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('insert into test_table values ({a}, {b}, {c})'.format(a=a, b=b, c=c))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Next, I created the test for your method by taking into account [how patch works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch). As you are dealing with os environment variables [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582750/python-mock-patch-os-environ-and-return-value) can help you understand why I mocked it that way.

An example implementation of the test could be as follows:

```
from psyco import insert
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock
import os

@patch.dict(os.environ,{'PGDB':'db_url'})
@patch('psycopg2.connect')
def test_insert_function(psycopg2_mock):

    x = 1
    y = 4
    z = 'xyz'
    sql_query = 'insert into test_table values ({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(x,y,z)
    insert(x,y,z)
    assert psycopg2_mock.return_value.cursor.call_count == 1
    psycopg2_mock.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.assert_called_with(sql_query)
    assert psycopg2_mock.return_value.commit.call_count == 1
    assert psycopg2_mock.return_value.close.call_count == 1
```

Comment: The questioner is not trying to patch the environment variable or `connect`. They're trying to patch `commit`.

Comment: @user2357112 I get yur point, I assumed that since it is a Unit Test you do not want to have external dependencies. That's why I proposed to both check that the `function call is schematically correct` and mocking the call to commit since `psycopg2.connect` call is a mock