# Mock or monkey patching using pytest

Tags: mocking, pytest, azure-pipelines

I'm very much new to the **pytest framework** and while I was exploring I checked with few terms such as mocking, monkey patching, etc. I basically understood the definition of each of them but having issues in applying them to my functional code. The init class of my parent method reads a few environment variables and pass them to the methods.

I am having difficulty applying the **mocking/monkey_patching** those variables and passing those test cases with fake data. To be precise, check the below example

Scenario:

```
class sampleDB(object):
    
    config_keys = ["foo_env", "bar_env", "foo_pass", "bar_pass"]

    def __init__(self, database, conf=None):
    
    os.environ["foo_env"] = os.getenv("foo_env")
    os.environ["bar_env"] = os.getenv("bar_env") 
    os.environ["foo_pass"] = os.getenv("foo_pass")
    os.environ["bar_pass"] = os.getenv("bar_pass")

    if not isinstance(conf, AnalyticsConfig):
         if conf is None:
              conf = AnalyticsConfig(require_only=self.CONFIG_KEYS)
         else:
              raise TypeError("'conf' must be an AnalyticsConfig instance")

    self.foo_env= conf.foo_env
    self.bar_env= conf.bar_env
    self.foo_pass= conf.foo_pass
    self.bar_pass= conf.bar_pass
    self._conf = conf
    self.database = database

  def sample_run(x,y):
   
   """Sample function to read data from a database and and returns pandas.df"""
 
   result = read_data(self.foo_env, self.foo_pass, x, y) 
   
   return result
```

The above code works in a regular **local test** environment by requesting **os.getenv variables**. When I deploy this code with the test cases in the **Azure pipeline**, it is failing because there are no environment variables set up in the pipeline. Instead of keeping the variable in pipeline, I want to use the **mocking/monkey patching** concept here.

Can someone please help me out with the problem?

Comment: You can use the the `setenv` method of the [monkeypatch fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-environment-variables), if you are using pytest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of keeping the variable in pipeline, I want to use the mocking/monkey patching concept here.

Since you do not want to keep the variable in pipeline, you could try to use the Mock to set environment variables in pytest:

```
import os
from unittest import mock

from example.settings import Colour, get_settings


@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"FROBNICATION_COLOUR": "ROUGE"})
def test_frobnication_colour():
    colour = get_settings().frobnication_colour
    assert colour == Colour.ROUGE
```

You could check following documents for some more details:

[How to Mock Environment Variables in pytest](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/10/13/how-to-mock-environment-variables-with-pytest/)

[Python mock Patch os.environ and return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582750/python-mock-patch-os-environ-and-return-value)

Comment: How to mock os.environ if environment var is accessed globally. like below
USER = os.environ['USER']
def get_user():
       return USER