# Code in context manager from one py test file affects another test file

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, contextmanager

I have test_a.py and test_b.py files. In test_a.py file I have context manager with `patch.dict` like below:

```
with patch.dict("os.environ", {"AWS_REGION": "us-east-1"}):
    code...
```

In test_b.py file I have `AWS_REGION = os.environ["AWS_REGION"]` .

The problem: when I commented out the context manager in test_a.py file, the test_b.py file failed because `os.environ` doesn't have `"AWS_REGION"` .

My question:

1. Why are the two files interdependent?
2. Acknowledging that they're interdependent, why the `patch.dict` that only applies in the **context manager** will have an effect on test_b.py file?

Comment: Are you running `test_b.py` inside the context manager?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the response. Nope I was not.

Comment: Are they in different threads of the same Python process? The environment is a global attribute of the process.

Comment: No I don't think so. I am using pytest to run those tests.

Comment: Can you then try another variant to mock environment variables please? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211725/12000849

Comment: @dukkee Thanks for the suggestion. That should work but I am curious what is happening out here.