# Pytest atomic test succeed but fail when running with other tests

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I want to test a import in a module `module.py` based on a variable environnement. To do that I use a fixture changing the var env and I test that in test_module.py.
If I run `pytest test/test_module.py` the test is succeed, but if I run `pytest test/` it fails, telling me the class if the Dummy one.

```py
# test/confest.py

from typing import Generator 

@pytest.fixture(scope="function") -> Generator[None, None, None]:
def change_var_env():
    some_env_var = os.getenv("ENV_VAR")
    os.environ["ENV_VAR"] = "True"

    yield None
    
    if some_env_var is not None:
        os.environ["ENV_VAR"] = some_env_var


# src/my_package/module.py

if os.getenv("ENV_VAR") == "True":
    instance_class = RealClass()
else:
    instance_class = DummyClass()


# test/test_module.py
import pytest

def test_import_module.py(change_var_env):
    from mypackage.module import instance_class
    assert isinstance(instance_class, RealClass)  # Succeed if running pytest test/test_module.py

# test/test_module_bis.py
import pytest

def test_import_module.py():
    from mypackage.module import instance_class
    assert isinstance(instance_class, DummyClass)
```

I tried many things:

1. reload the module with `importlib.reload(module)`
2. ```
   import sys

   del sys.modules['module']
   import module
   ```
3. put the fixture at the module scope, not only function scope
4. ensuring the fixture works well (it is, var env is set at "True")

Answer (score 1):

I think your unit test shouldn't depend on external state (a database, a file on your computer or a environment variable).
Otherwise you will have dependencies between your tests (like concurrency with your database).
You should mock your environment variable. There are several examples : [Python mock Patch os.environ and return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582750/python-mock-patch-os-environ-and-return-value)

Comment: I tried `monkeypatch.setenv()`option, it still fails.

Comment: Tried `with patch.dict(os.environ, {"ENV_VAR": "True"}, clear=True) as mock_env:` still fail. The env var is at true anyway, I think the issue is during import, like if the import was done before or not using the current var env